# JavaScript function is not working in ASP.NET application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Given below function is not working in my ASP.NET application.

```js
function sum() {

    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtrd').value;
    var txtsecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtintalment').value;
    var txtthirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtprd').value;
    var txtfourNumberValue = document.getElementById('Penality').value;
    var txtFiveNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtint').value;
    var txtsixNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtsbint').value;
                  
    var result = (parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) +   parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtthirdNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtfourNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtFiveNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtsixNumberValue)).toFixed(2);
 
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('txttp').value = result;
    }
 }
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: you need to give more information. Add your **html** file or the file that you connected with this script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **`typo error`** in `txtSecondNumberValue` variable you declare variable as `txtsecondNumberValue` and accessing as `txtSecondNumberValue`.

Please correct the variable name.

```
var txtsecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtintalment').value;
var result = (parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtthirdNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtfourNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtFiveNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtsixNumberValue)).toFixed(2);
```

Here is the working example,

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtrd').value;
  var txtsecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtintalment').value;
  var txtthirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtprd').value;
  var txtfourNumberValue = document.getElementById('Penality').value;
  var txtFiveNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtint').value;
  var txtsixNumberValue = document.getElementById('txtsbint').value;
  var result = (parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtsecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtthirdNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtfourNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtFiveNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtsixNumberValue)).toFixed(2);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('txttp').value = result;
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 9fr;
}
input {
   width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>First: <input id="txtrd" type="number" value="10">
Second: <input id="txtintalment" type="number" value="10">
Third: <input id="txtprd" type="number" value="10">
Fourth: <input id="Penality" type="number" value="10">
Fifth: <input id="txtint" type="number" value="10">
Sixth: <input id="txtsbint" type="number" value="10">
Result: <input id="txttp" type="number" value="" disabled>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="sum()">Calculate</button>
```